# fprintf C multiple spaces

Tags: c, printf

Hello i'm new to C and have some confusion Regarding `fprintf`

I'm trying to create a Data table and i want it to look exactly like this:

```
Rectangle A                    Rectangle B 
SW corner   Height   Width     SW corner   Height   Width
```

Most of my confusion is coming from the white spaces, surely there is a better way than just adding an empty String.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use width specifier:

```
printf("[%5d] [%-5d]\n", 42, 42);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can give a field width with the format specifier:

```
printf( "%20s", str );
```

You can also make contents left- or right-aligned within that field, and many other things. It's really worth checking out the details of the documentation: [man printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

Answer (score 0):

printf has lots of options, is this what you had in mind?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {

    char *label1="Rectangle A";
    char *label2="Rectangle B";

    printf("%-31s%-31s\n",label1,label2);
    printf("SW corner   Height   Width     SW corner   Height   Width\n");
}
```